# Conversion of pipe delimited single column data to multiple column matrix - R

Tags: r

I need some help with data manipulation in R. I have a long code which does this as a series of steps, but I am looking for a shorter way to do it.

Here is a data frame which has two columns - the first one is an ID and the other has pipe delimited data in it as shown below:

```
ID  DATA
1   a
2   a|b
3   b|c
4   d|e
```

I need to convert this to this form:

```
ID  a  b  c  d  e
1  1  0  0  0  0
2  1  1  0  0  0
3  0  1  1  0  0
4  0  0  0  1  1
```

I am hoping there is a simpler way to do this than the lengthy code I have.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4):

This works on the supplied data. First read in your data:

```
pipdat <- read.table(stdin(),header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
ID  DATA
1   a
2   a|b
3   b|c
4   d|e

# leave a blank line at the end so it stops reading
```

Now here goes:

```
nr <- dim(pipdat)[1]
chrs <- strsplit(pipdat[,2],"[|]")
af <- unique(unlist(chrs))
whichlet <- function(a,fac) as.numeric(fac %in% a)
matrix(unlist(lapply(chrs,whichlet,af)),
        byrow=TRUE,nr=nr,dimnames=list(ID=1:nr,af))
```

(That can be done in fewer lines, but it's handy to see what some of those steps do)

It produces:

```
ID  a b c d e
  1 1 0 0 0 0
  2 1 1 0 0 0
  3 0 1 1 0 0
  4 0 0 0 1 1
```

I guessed from your post that you wanted ID as row names; if you need it to be a column of data that last line needs to be different.

I'd have used `sapply` instead of `lapply`, but you end up with the transpose of the desired matrix. That works if you replace the last line with:

```
res <- t(sapply(chrs,whichlet,af))
dimnames(res) <- list(ID=1:nr,af)
res
```

but it might be slower.

---

If you don't follow the line

```
matrix(unlist(lapply(chrs,whichlet,af)),
        byrow=TRUE,nr=nr,dimnames=list(ID=1:nr,af))
```

just break it up from the innermost function outward:

```
lres <- lapply(chrs,whichlet,af)
vres <- unlist(lres)
matrix(vres,byrow=TRUE,nr=nr,dimnames=list(ID=1:nr,af))
```

---

If you need ID as a column of data instead of row names, one way to do it is:

```
lres <- lapply(chrs,whichlet,af)
vres <- unlist(lres)
cbind(ID=1:nr,matrix(vres,byrow=TRUE,nr=nr,dimnames=list(1:nr,af)))
```

or you could do

```
res <- t(sapply(chrs,whichlet,af))
dimnames(res) <- list(1:nr,af)
cbind(ID=1:nr,res)
```

Comment: Brilliant - Thanks! I will take some time and understand your last line - but I sure will.

Comment: See changes to my answer which might explain more - both the note about the ID as row names and the part at the end about the last line.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. But, thanks again. I have learnt a tonne of R by just following your code.